# Java android cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA

Tags: java, android

My application sometimes works fine but sometimes in logs I see this :

```
05-18 18:39:23.281 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=gps-***.pl; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-18 18:39:23.282 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-18 18:39:23.282 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=gps-***.pl; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-18 18:39:23.282 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
05-18 18:39:23.284 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: gps-***.pl get result from proxy gai_error = 0
05-18 18:39:23.285 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=94.42.199.202; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-18 18:39:23.285 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-18 18:39:29.464 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=gps-***.pl; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-18 18:39:29.464 12680 12722 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-18 18:39:29.903 12680 12722 E NativeCrypto: ssl=0xaf5a18c0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x9e5f3c6c arg=0x0
05-18 18:39:29.903 12680 12722 E NativeCrypto: ssl=0xaf5a18c0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```